# VS 2019 fails to use previous environment when existing solution is started

Tags: visual-studio

I am using visual studio 2019 community and using python. I have several existing solutions and several different existing environments.
The VS error is ;- When I open an existing solution VS fails to use the specific environment that was previous assigned and activated in that solution... VS incorrectly always uses one other environment. This error happens no matter how often I set the correct environment with "use this environment for the default for new projects", and regardless if I replace the wrong environment with the specific existing environment required by the project. VS 2019 is at version 16.11.27 .

Efforts to resolve the VS 2019 error;-

1. I re-opened VS with an existing solution and changed the environment that is used and activated by that existing solution / project and saved all,
   closed the solution and closed VS 2019 - but the error still re-occurs when I relaunch VS and the solution.
2. I set the "use this environment for the default for new projects" to the correct existing environment required by the project, and also included that correct environment in the project, and activated it, I removed the incorrect environment from the solution, then saved all, closed the solution then closed VS - but the error still reoccurs.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Selection-of-Python-Environment-is-not-p/1528933?q=python+environment